# Toolbar using appcompact v21 with custom view

Tags: android, android-actionbar, toolbar, android-appcompat, material-design

I want to implement **Toolbar** using appcompat v21 like following image.

[image]

I need those action buttons and also I want to implement some custom view attach below actionbar. I have read few guidelines and thought Toolbar might be the appropriate one. So I tried implementing tool bar. The below image is the result what I got.

[image]

Can anyone please explain how to implement? Like those custom edittext and textview i want to add few more views. Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Toolbar` is just a regular `ViewGroup` and so you can put any `View`s either custom or non-custom inside it in XML. Like in every `ViewGroup` element. And you can style it however you want.

Comment: Yeah Thanks for your tips, even i tried the same thing i tried after posting this. Well it worked fine! Appreciate your answer!